# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Function "getDonators" requires 1 arguments, but undefined were provided

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, solidity, web3js, web3-react

I am building a crowdfunding blockchain application and I am getting the above error.

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Function "getDonators" requires 1 arguments, but undefined were provided.
> Expected function signature: contract.call("getDonators", _id: BigNumberish): Promise<string[], BigNumber[]>

This the code for the part where I am calling getDonators function

```
const getDonations = async (pId) => {
    const donations = await contract.call('getDonators', pId); //HERE! 
    const numberOfDonations = donations[0].length;

    const parsedDonations = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < numberOfDonations; i++) {
      parsedDonations.push({
        donator: donations[0][i],
        donation: ethers.utils.formatEther(donations[1][i].toString())
      })
    }

    return parsedDonations;
  }
```

This is the code that is present in the Solidity File

```
    function getDonators(uint256 _id) view public returns (address[] memory, uint256[] memory) {
        return (campaigns[_id].donators, campaigns[_id].donations);
```

Please help me resolve this issue. Am I not passing the parameters correctly ?

I tried to pass parameters in various ways but it didnt really fixed the issue.
Also I tried to call the function(in .sol file) in a different manner like this :

```
await contract.donateToCampaign(pId, {
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther(amount.toString())
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPD** : I actually resolved the error, replacing the erroneous line of code with :

```
const donations = await contract.call('getDonators', [pId]); //HERE!
```

https://portal.thirdweb.com/typescript/sdk.smartcontract.call

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The possible error I can see in your code is from this line:

> const getDonations = async (pId) => {

The `pId` may be `undefined` in the first place.
Try to `console.log` to see if it is actually an integer

```
const getDonations = async (pId) => {
    console.log('pId:', pId); //Add the code here
    const donations = await contract.call('getDonators', pId);
//...
```

Comment: I have done that and it shows the correct project id, also I console log-ed the typeof(pId). 
I actually resolved this error just by replacing pId with [pId]. I really do not understand why are we passing it as an array object tho.